# 2-opt algorithm for traveling salesman

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I wrote a 2-opt algorithm to be used in a program and noticed (using profile) that the 2-opt is eating up a lot of time. I have tried a few things to make it run faster, but I am out of ideas. Any tips on making it run faster, or a better way to write a 2-opt algo?

```
def twoOpt(self):
    '''Peforms 2-opt search to improve route'''
    for index, route in enumerate(self.routes):
        for element in xrange(len(route.fields)):
            i = element + 1
            k = i + 1
            while k <= len(route.fields):
                newRoute = Route(route.scout)
                for field in self.twoOptSwap(route.fields, i, k):
                    newRoute.addField(field)
                newRoute.calcRouteCost()
                if newRoute.cost < route.cost:
                    self.routes[index] = newRoute
                k += 1

def twoOptSwap(self, fields, i, k):
    start = fields[0:i]
    middle = fields[i:k]
    middle = middle[::-1]
    end = fields[k:]
    newFields = start + middle + end
    return newFields
```

Each route object contains a list of fields (`route.fields`) and `route.calcRouteCost()` sets `route.cost` with a value.

Comment: These appear to be two methods of a class. Could you include the whole class? Also show an example what the input data structure and the output look like.

Answer (score 3):

- A slice of a list is a new list, so this code constructs five lists:

  ```
  start = fields[0:i]
  middle = fields[i:k]
  middle = middle[::-1]
  end = fields[k:]
  newFields = start + middle + end
  ```

  This is probably faster:

  ```
  newFields = fields[:]
  newFields[i:k] = fields[k-1:i-1:-1]
  ```
- Instead of adding fields one by one in the code below, you could change `Route` to accept the list of fields in the constructor.

  ```
  newRoute = Route(route.scout)
  for field in self.twoOptSwap(route.fields, i, k):
      newRoute.addField(field)
  ```

  Note also that after reversing a segment of the route, a complete recalculation of cost is not necessary. You only need to consider how the cost changes where the segments join, assuming cost does not depend on direction of travel.
- Instead of

  ```
  for element in xrange(len(route.fields)):
      i = element + 1
  ```

  simply

  ```
  for i in xrange(1, len(route.fields) + 1):
  ```
- Instead of a `while` loop

  ```
  k = i + 1
  while k <= len(route.fields):
      ...
      k += 1
  ```

  a `for` loop

  ```
  for k in xrange(i + 1, len(route.fields) + 1):
  ```